# C# why use a local variable to hold a member variable before calling its methods when thinking about thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was reading the source code of ConcurrentQueue:

```
public void Enqueue(T item)
{
    SpinWait spin = new SpinWait();
    while (true)
    {
        // Why use a local variable to hold a member variable?
        // If we call m_tail.TryAppend() directly, is there any risk if
        // another thread was tring to change the value of m_tail while calling?
        Segment tail = m_tail;
        if (tail.TryAppend(item))
            return;
        spin.SpinOnce();
    }
}
```

I want to know the reason.

Comment: I don't think it matters in this specific case, but it would matter if you are doing multiple things to `m_tail`. I think it might just be a (good) habit of the author's to always put fields in a local first, just in case one wants to do multiple things to it.

Comment: Where did you find this code? The current [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/312dbe453224780a2eb3665fec1b1b8fb6b176c1/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs#L602) of the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is different.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias-  looks like the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs,577) but that doesn't contain the comment shown

Comment: I think the comment is from the OP